# Efficient casting of float array to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, casting

Well this question may have been asked before but I could not find an exact match so I will give it a try.

I want to cast a `float[]` to a `byte[]` in way a single `float` would be cast (with loss of information etc), meaning I want to keep only the last 8bits of each `float` in the array. I found some code involving ByteBuffer, but this approach converted all 32bit of each float to 4 bytes (of 8 bits each) which is not the desired output (if someone is interested though, the link is http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18962.html)

I did not find any code for this casting so I just used a classic `for` loop:

```
public static byte[] float2ByteArray(float floatArray[]) {
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[floatArray.length]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < floatArray.length; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = (byte) floatArray[i];
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

My question is if there is a more efficient way to achieve the same result that I am not aware of?

Comment: Are you having performance problems with this particular loop?

Comment: >"in way a single float would be casted (with loss of information etc) meaning I want to keep only the last 8bits of each float in the array."

This is not how the float -> byte conversion works in Java.

Comment: how long is your array?

Comment: Are you by any chance hoping to cast floats in some range to the full range of byte values?

Comment: @DanGetz if he wants the last 8 bits, the sign shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: I am not sure why you want the last 8 bits, if its a single precision floating point then remember that, the first bit is the sign, the next 8 bit the exponent and the last remaining bits are for fraction. I hope you know what you are doing - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: This approach casts the numerical value of the float to the nearest byte value...approximately.

Comment: It's not the way float -> byte conversion works in any language. The last 8 bits of a single precision IEEE-754 number is the LSB of the mantissa, so is absolutely useless, as any meaningful numerical expression relating to the original number. If what you want to do is instead truncate the value, you will need an algorithm for that, Which among other things, determines what happens to numbers that are too large, or too small to fit in a byte.

Comment: Maybe the last 8 bits was erroneous. I was carried away by the `int` -> `byte` casting. What I meant was I just want the truncated value of `float` as in 5.0 -> 5. As for the performance this casting is going to happen some million times so the more efficient the better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general approach with the loop is the way to go. One may tinker with the loop structure (unrolling etc.) to gain a few percent better performance, but thats generally something you only want to bother with at the very end of functional development (if at all).

Whats more of a problem here is that you do not check if your floats *fit* into a byte. Due to java's (somewhat peculiar) semantics for operations with data types smaller than int, the cast:

```
byte b = (byte) floatValue;
```

Can result in *very* ugly surprises when the float value exceeds the range of a byte. Because implicitly this conversion works as follows:

```
int i = (int) floatValue;
byte b = (byte) i;
```

And *that* is not what you will intuitively expect. If floatValue *fits* into an int, but not a byte, your final byte value will be the *truncated* int value. So for example:

```
float f = 256F;
byte b = (byte) f;
```

Results in a byte value of 0 (*zero*), not 127 as one would ordinarily expect. Be wary of that and round/clip your float value accordingly before casting.

As far as performance goes, float -> int/byte cast is by far the most costly operation here (per element).

Comment: Thank you for the analysis. I really don't have an issue about the float fitting into the byte because it's just rgb values casted to float for arithmetic reasons. The whole idea is to make this conversion in memory than reading again the input image file, which I guess it's costlier, isn't?

Comment: @Eypros If the cast semantics aren't a problem in your use case your code should do just fine. I wouldn't worry about the performance of this conversion too much, most likely whatever else your program does will take much more time, so spending a lot of brain power here will yield little return in terms of performance.